# How to make the left margin one inch on the List of Tables and List of Figures pages,

Tags: table-of-contents

It is more than 1 inch on Point 1.1 Correlation .....

[image]

```
 \listfiles
%\documentclass[12pt]{IEEEtran}
%\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{thesis}
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}
%\documentclass[14pt,reqno]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in,left=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in}
%\pagestyle{empty}
\linespread{2}
%\usepackage{blindtext}


\setlength{\parindent}{3em}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\raggedbottom



\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{makecell}
%\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{appendix}
%\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
%\DontPrintSemicolon
%`{\nomname}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
%\makenomenclature
\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG, .eps, .tiff}

%\urlstyle{same}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
%\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}




\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\medskip}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

%\pagestyle{myheadings} \markright{\today}

%\pagenumbering{alph}




\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{-2}

%\input Title

%---------------------------------------------------------
% Continue with the front-matter pages in the following
% order:  Copyright (opt.), Thesis/Dissertation Approval
% Page, Abstract (required for theses and dissertations),
% Dedication (opt.) Acknowledgments (opt.),
% Preface/Foreword (opt.), Table of Contents,
% List of Tables (if any),  List of Figures (if any).
%---------------------------------------------------------

%%  Comment out any of the commands below to eliminate
%%  whichever page you won't need in your paper.


    
    
    

    






    
\addtocontents{toc}{\vspace{-0.45in} \underline{CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    
%\addtocontents{toc}{{CHAPTER}{PAGE}\par}

\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}
    
    \addtocontents{lot}{\vspace{-0.45in} \underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    \addtocontents{lof}{\vspace{-0.45in} \underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}
    %\listoftables % comment out if no tables
    \renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{#1~}
    
\tableofcontents
{%
    %       \let\oldnumberline\numberline% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %       \renewcommand{\numberline}{\tablename~\oldnumberline}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \listoftables%
}

{%
    %       \let\oldnumberline\numberline% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    %       \renewcommand{\numberline}{\figurename~\oldnumberline}%<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    \listoffigures%
}





%---------------------------------------------------------
% Set page numbers to arabic (1,2,...), and include
% the paper sections in the following order:  Introduction
% (if any), Chapters, Bibliography (references), and Vita.
%---------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\raggedright
\parindent=.35in

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------SECTION------------------------------------------------%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%


    \chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Correlation Coefficients of the Compared Frameworks in Terms of the Success Rate } % title of Table
        \label{table:correlation1} % is used to refer this table in the text
        {\footnotesize              
        }           
    \end{center}
\end{table} 


\end{document}
```

Comment: Are the `siugrad51` document class files available online? Please advise.

Comment: yes it is my school format: https://math.siu.edu/graduate/template.php

Comment: Keep in mind that the figure.table numbers are right aligned, so the "extra margin" is really just leaving room for larger numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I corrected the preamble settings to avoid conflicting specs.

For clarity, I removed the already commented lines in your MWE and marked the modified ones.

Finally I changed erroneous `\vspace{...}` to `\hspace{...}`

[image: x2]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\listfiles 
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{siugrad51}

\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\geometry{top=1in,left=1in,bottom=1in,right=1in}

\linespread{2}

%\setlength{\parindent}{3em}  % commented
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\raggedbottom

%\usepackage[titles]{tocloft} % commented
%\setlength{\cftbeforechapskip}{3pt} % commented

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{appendix}

\graphicspath{{images/}}
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.PNG, .eps, .tiff}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}

\usepackage{ragged2e} % changed
\usepackage[bookmarks=false]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage[titletoc,title]{appendix} % commented
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{7}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}


\titlecontents{chapter}[0em]{\medskip}
{\MakeUppercase{\chaptername}\enspace \thecontentslabel.\enspace}
{}
{\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\titlerule*[1pc]{.}\contentspage}
%------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\setcounter{page}{-2}

%\input Title

%---------------------------------------------------------
% Continue with the front-matter pages in the following
% order:  Copyright (opt.), Thesis/Dissertation Approval
% Page, Abstract (required for theses and dissertations),
% Dedication (opt.) Acknowledgments (opt.),
% Preface/Foreword (opt.), Table of Contents,
% List of Tables (if any),  List of Figures (if any).
%---------------------------------------------------------

%%  Comment out any of the commands below to eliminate
%%  whichever page you won't need in your paper.

\addtocontents{toc}{\hspace{-2.5em}{CHAPTER} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par} % <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed to hspace 

\renewcommand\listfigurename{LIST OF FIGURES}
\renewcommand\listtablename{LIST OF TABLES}

\addtocontents{lot}{\hspace{-2.5em}\underline{TABLE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed to hspace
\addtocontents{lof}{\hspace{-2.5em}\underline{FIGURE} ~\hfill \underline{PAGE}\par}% <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< changed to hspace
%\listoftables % comment out if no tables

\tableofcontents
\listoftables%
\listoffigures%


%---------------------------------------------------------
% Set page numbers to arabic (1,2,...), and include
% the paper sections in the following order:  Introduction
% (if any), Chapters, Bibliography (references), and Vita.
%---------------------------------------------------------

\newpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
%\raggedright
\parindent=.35in

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%
%------------------------------------------------SECTION------------------------------------------------%
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

    \chapter{Introduction}

\begin{table}[htb]
    \begin{center}
        \caption{Correlation Coefficients of the Compared Frameworks in Terms of the Success Rate } % title of Table
        \label{table:correlation1} % is used to refer this table in the text
        {\footnotesize              
        }           
    \end{center}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```